# Slider not appearing on home page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider

I have a problem where I can't get an image slider to appear on my home page.

It should be located here:http://new.solacetree.org/.

Right between Grief Programs and Publications & Resources.

I am using the shortcode for both Easing Slider (v.2.2.1.1) and Soliloquy (v.2.3.0) in WordPress v.4.2:

```
[soliloquy slug="home-pubs"]
[easingslider id="2009"]
```

It does work on another page here: http://new.solacetree.org/publications-resources/ As you can see, both sliders appear.

The only difference between the two pages is that the home page has two sidebars and the other page has one.

I am not sure what is missing from the home page that is on the other page that makes it not work.

I found that in the Footer I am missing the following codes on the home page but that are on the other page:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='soliloquy-lite-style-css'  href='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/soliloquy-lite/assets/css/soliloquy.css?ver=2.3.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='easingslider-css'  href='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/css/easingslider.min.css?ver=2.2.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/soliloquy-lite/assets/js/min/soliloquy-min.js?ver=2.3.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/js/jquery.easingslider.min.js?ver=2.2.1.1'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">if ( typeof soliloquy_slider === 'undefined' || false === soliloquy_slider ) {soliloquy_slider = {};}jQuery('#soliloquy-container-2011').css('height', Math.round(jQuery('#soliloquy-container-2011').width()/(550/200)));jQuery(window).load(function(){var $ = jQuery;var soliloquy_container_2011 = $('#soliloquy-container-2011'),soliloquy_2011 = $('#soliloquy-2011');soliloquy_slider['2011'] = soliloquy_2011.soliloquy({slideSelector: '.soliloquy-item',speed: 400,pause: 5000,auto: 1,useCSS: 0,keyboard: true,adaptiveHeight: 1,adaptiveHeightSpeed: 400,infiniteLoop: 1,mode: 'fade',pager: 1,controls: 1,nextText: '',prevText: '',startText: '',stopText: '',onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-active-slide').removeClass('soliloquy-active-slide');soliloquy_container_2011.css({'height':'auto','background-image':'none'});if ( soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-slider li').size() > 1 ) {soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-controls').fadeTo(300, 1);}soliloquy_2011.find('.soliloquy-item:not(.soliloquy-clone):eq(' + currentIndex + ')').addClass('soliloquy-active-slide');soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-clone').find('*').removeAttr('id');},onSlideBefore: function(element, oldIndex, newIndex){soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-active-slide').removeClass('soliloquy-active-slide');$(element).addClass('soliloquy-active-slide');},onSlideAfter: function(element, oldIndex, newIndex){},});});</script>
```

There is code in between these lines where I have left spaces so I don't think it is something with the function:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I did add the following to my functions.php file which the theme creator said to do to set up the double sidebars on one page. I don't see how it would change the way things are displayed in the footer but it is there if it will help.

```
/* Home Page Layout */
add_filter( 'generate_sidebar_layout','generate_custom_homepage_sidebar_layout' );
function generate_custom_homepage_sidebar_layout( $layout )
{
    // If we are on a woocommerce page, set the sidebar
    if ( is_front_page() )
        return 'both-sidebars';

    // Or else, set the regular layout
    return $layout;

 }
```

EDIT: I removed the function above and it didn't change anything so I left it in there.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On your homepage html it seems to be missing the JS and CSS for the sliders

eg

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='soliloquy-lite-style-css'  href='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/soliloquy-lite/assets/css/soliloquy.css?ver=2.3.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='easingslider-css'  href='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/css/easingslider.min.css?ver=2.2.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/soliloquy-lite/assets/js/min/soliloquy-min.js?ver=2.3.0'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.solacetree.org/wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/js/jquery.easingslider.min.js?ver=2.2.1.1'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">if ( typeof soliloquy_slider === 'undefined' || false === soliloquy_slider ) {soliloquy_slider = {};}jQuery('#soliloquy-container-2011').css('height', Math.round(jQuery('#soliloquy-container-2011').width()/(550/200)));jQuery(window).load(function(){var $ = jQuery;var soliloquy_container_2011 = $('#soliloquy-container-2011'),soliloquy_2011 = $('#soliloquy-2011');soliloquy_slider['2011'] = soliloquy_2011.soliloquy({slideSelector: '.soliloquy-item',speed: 400,pause: 5000,auto: 1,useCSS: 0,keyboard: true,adaptiveHeight: 1,adaptiveHeightSpeed: 400,infiniteLoop: 1,mode: 'fade',pager: 1,controls: 1,nextText: '',prevText: '',startText: '',stopText: '',onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-active-slide').removeClass('soliloquy-active-slide');soliloquy_container_2011.css({'height':'auto','background-image':'none'});if ( soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-slider li').size() > 1 ) {soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-controls').fadeTo(300, 1);}soliloquy_2011.find('.soliloquy-item:not(.soliloquy-clone):eq(' + currentIndex + ')').addClass('soliloquy-active-slide');soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-clone').find('*').removeAttr('id');},onSlideBefore: function(element, oldIndex, newIndex){soliloquy_container_2011.find('.soliloquy-active-slide').removeClass('soliloquy-active-slide');$(element).addClass('soliloquy-active-slide');},onSlideAfter: function(element, oldIndex, newIndex){},});});</script>
```

And the DIV's for sliders themselves are not being outputted into the code

`<div class="soliloquy-wrapper"></div>` `<div class="easingslider"></div>`

Comment: I noticed that, now the question is why? It works on any other page, why is the home page excluded from having divs, stylesheets, and javascript.

Comment: @MattM do you have wp_head() and wp_footer() in the right places?

(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) 

(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)

Try some of these methods to debug your problem

[reference](http://www.bestwebsitesdesigner.com/web-design/wordpress-easing-slider-not-loading-images-css-issue/#more-1146)